# How to configure LWC to accept and map a JSON string as Input variable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, visual-workflow, json

I am trying to modify my LWC, which launches a Flow, to accept a JSON string as input with any variables that I want to pass to the flow defined in the JSON string. Reason is to allow the LWC to be very flexible vs listing each variable name I wish to pass into each different flow.

I have two inputs `flowName` which is working fine and `flowParams` which is supposed to be the JSON string.

1. I do not think the `get inputVariables()` is written correctly and likely needs to map the string? If so I do not understand what that should look like.

```
<template>
    <lightning-flow
        flow-api-name={flowName}
        flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
        onstatuschange={handleStatusChange}
        flow-finish-behavior="NONE"
    >
    </lightning-flow>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class CardNpiSingFlowCmp extends LightningElement {
  @api flowName;
  @api flowParams;

    get inputVariables() {
      return this.flowParams;
    }
    
    handleStatusChange(event) {
        if (event.detail.status === 'FINISHED') {
            // set behavior after a finished flow interview
        }
    }
}
```

2. In the Properties for the LWC what the JSON string should look like when passed in?

`[{ name: 'varEntryPoint', type: 'String', value: 'lwcType1' },{ name: 'varTwo', type: 'String', value: 'lwcType2' }]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.flowParams` must not be a JSON string, but rather a JavaScript object.

If you are receiving it as a JSON string, consider updating how it is passed in. If you can't change this to a JavaScript object (array), use `JSON.parse` to convert it to the array of values you need before it gets passed to the flow. E.g.

```
get inputVariables() {
  return JSON.parse(this.flowParams);
}
```

The format of the objects in the array is as you have shown, and as covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_embed_input_variables_example), though to be valid JSON the property names ("name", "type" and "value") must be in double quotes.